# Composite index to cover sum of columns

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-5.7

Is it possible to create an index in MySQL that will help with a query like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM `table`
WHERE a + b + c > 0
```

I've tried adding a composite index on all `a`, `b`, and `c` to no avail. Is there any way to optimize a query like this where the condition is based on a mathematical calculation?

Comment: Are you going to use only this type of condition `WHERE a + b + c > @some_constant`? Or various different formulas?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - for this query it will always be exactly the same. And in general, this same calculation is all I need to optimize for.

Comment: OK. Please add the version of MySQL you intend to use.

Comment: You can use a generated column: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html and index it.

Comment: version is 5.7.25. looks like your suggestion would work here.  If you want to detail it in an answer I will happily accept it.  thanks.